# I cannot download software or use `sudo`

Tags: sudo

[image: Terminal]

This is what happens when i use `sudo`.

Plus I can't update Ubuntu and I can't open the Software Center.

Comment: The error message clearly tells you the problem. Fix the file permissions on your system. Why did you change them in the first place?

Comment: Seems like your /etc/sudoers file (the one which controls who can use root privileges) had its permissions messed up. If you have an Ubuntu (or another GNU/Linux) live media I can give an answer.

Comment: @dobey If he can't use sudo how would he do it? Root's password is unwritable by default in Ubuntu.

Comment: what is the original file permission and how do I change it

Comment: I did not change it

Comment: @Bobj2008 something was messed up in your system. You can't do it with your regular user right now. I'm not saying that you changed it, but someone (or something) did. Maybe it was you, by accident? Again, if you have a GNU/Linux Live Media I can help you.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiZgU.png

Comment: I dont have Live Media

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Instead, copy-paste the text, and use the formatting tools to make it look nice. (For more details, see [Why do people post screenshots of their terminals?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/301745) and the [formatting guide](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code))

Answer (score 6):

`sudo` is unuseable, but you still have `pkexec`.

So:

```
pkexec chmod 440 /etc/sudoers
```

Comment: @Bobj2008 No problem :). You may accept this answer by clicking on the tick under the answer's score to indicate that this answer solved your problem: https://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer.

Comment: Uh oh... http://i.stack.imgur.com/HerYz.png

Comment: @Bobj2008 Ok `pkexec chmod 755 /etc/sudoers.d` should fix that as well, however that's not normal. Did you run some strange command recently? Let me know if `pkexec chmod 755 /etc/sudoers.d` fixes that for good, however be aware that your installation looks corrupted. There might be other folders / files with the wrong permissions, or even worse things. If you remember having run some command which changed some permissions recursively please post it.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so your main problem is that /etc/sudoers is "writable." as stated by that error message you were getting

```
chmod 440 /etc/sudoers
```

that changes the file permission so that it isn't "global writable" and rather just readable to root.

also ensure that the file is owned by root

```
ls -l /etc/sudoers
```

that should give you something that looks like

```
-r--r----- 1 root root     745 Feb 10  2014 sudoers
```

the -r--r----- root root is the important part. If it's different, then you'll have to change the files ownership, but I doubt that could get screwed up.

I'm thinking that should fix your problem. Try that and let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/lR0Ed.png